# Not able to create an virtual environment using pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm trying to create an virtual environment with Python 3.7, using the `pipenv` command. Trying to run `pipenv install --python=python3.7` gives the error below:

```
pipenv install --python=python3.7 

loading virtual environment veriables

Creating a virtual environment for this project

Using path/to/python3.7 (3.7.0) to create virtualenv...

Creating virtual environment... Already using interpreter path/to/python3.7


New python executable in /home/user/.local/share/myproject/bin/python3.7

Not overwriting existing python script /home/user/.local/share/myproject/bin/python (you must use /home/user/.local/share/myproject/bin/python3.7)

failed to create a virtual environment.
```

How can I create a virtual environment using `pipenv`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to create a virtual environment, try with these commands

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv 
# After this installation 
python -m virtualenv vnvname
or
python3 -m virtualenv vnvname
```

## It will create a virtual environment

Comment: Hi Rajat, thanks for your response,

i am still getting same error as , i did below commands.

virtualenv --version 
-->16.4.3

which python3.7
-->path/to/python3.7

virtualenv -p python3.7 myproject

--> same error msg... Not overwrtting existing scripts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **virtualenv** command

```
virtualenv -p python3 envname
```

Update :

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Comment: Hi Kshitij, thanks for your response,

i am still getting same error as , i did below commands.

virtualenv --version 
-->16.4.3

which python3.7
-->path/to/python3.7

virtualenv -p python3.7 myproject

--> same error msg... Not overwrtting existing scripts

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in PyCharm using Kubuntu (Linux)

> Failed to create virtual environment

Found the answer in here [Create a Python3 virtual environment](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/linux-virtual-delivery-agent/current-release/configuration/create-a-python3-virtual-environment.html) to just run this command

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-dev python3-pip libkrb5-dev
```